# Attach custom object to QStandardItem in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm using `QTreeView` to show some data to the user. What I want is to attach an actual object to each node represented using `QStandardItem`.

To save the object reference into `QStandardItem`:

```
QStandardItem *child = new QStandardItem(s);
child->setFlags(child->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
child->setData(QVariant(QVariant::UserType, i), Qt::UserRole + 10);
```

To access the actual object when it is clicked in the UI:

```
void MyOtherClass::handleTreeViewSelectionChanged(const QModelIndex &i)
{
     MyClass* o = i.data(Qt::UserRole + 10).value<MyClass*>();
     // do other stuff with o
}
```

The above call just returns `NULL`.
Anybody knows how to deal with such a requirement?

I found absolutely nothing useful on the web.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To store your item in the QStandardItem you need to make sure that you've registered your type with QMetaType. For example, you might have this definition:

```
class MyType
{
public:
    MyType() : m_data(0) {}
    int someMethod() const { return m_data; }

private:
    int m_data;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType*);  // notice that I've declared this for a POINTER to your type
```

Then you would store it into a QVariant like so:

```
MyType *object = new MyType;
QVariant variant;
variant.setValue(object);
```

Given a properly registered metatype for your type, you can now do something like this with your QStandardItems:

```
MyType *object = new MyType;
QStandardItemModel model;
QStandardItem *parentItem = model.invisibleRootItem();
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
item->setData(QVariant::fromValue(myType));  // this defaults to Qt::UserRole + 1
parentItem->appendRow(item);
```

And then later extract it:

```
void MyOtherClass::handleTreeViewSelectionChanged(const QModelIndex &i)
{
     MyType* o = i.data(Qt::UserRole + 1).value<MyType*>();
     // do other stuff with o
}
```

Comment: Note, that in addition to above you might want to support Drag&Drop with those custom objects. To do so, you need to register stream operators for that type with `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators()`, see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators

Comment: Don't forget to add #include <QMetaType>